# How to know which loaders and plugins to use when using webpack with a certain module

Tags: webpack

I am new to Webpack and one thing confuses me.

For example, when I require bootstrap.css in my jsx file. It fails and tells me that webpack doesn't know what to do with certain types of file extensions that bootstrap.css depends on.

Let's say, I just want to use a certain part of bootstrap.css that has nothing to do with those file extensions.

Should I still define a loader for every file extension that bootstrap has an association with?

Also if one goes along and wants to define loader for all file extensions that bootstrap is associated with, then how do I know what file extensions to handle in advance instead of running webpack and adding loaders as it complains? How is it handled in terms of best practices?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [loaders](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/) for different assets.

Webpack by default know only how to handle JavaScript files when you import file.

For other types of assets you need to use loaders: css-loader, url loader

Here is the list of plugins available with [details](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but my question already acknowledges loaders. This doesn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: could you add the errors of bootstrap.css where it fails and complains on these extensions. which extensions bootstrap complains about (the full error log)